# Strange lag when sending large message using tcp_nodelay

Tags: c, node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a c program that sends the output of a bash shell over a tcp connection. To make my program more responsive, I used setsockopt() to enable TCP_NODELAY, which disables Nagle's buffering algorithm. This worked great, except rarely there is a lag in large messages. As in, if the message is more than around 500 bytes (probably 512). The first 500 bytes will go through (quickly in small messages), then there'll be a 1-2 second delay before the rest is received all at once. This only happens once every 10-15 times a large message is received. On the server side, the message is being written to the socket one byte at a time, and all of the bytes are available, so this behavior is unexpected to me.

My best guess is that there's a 512 byte buffer somewhere in the socket that's causing a block? I did some time tests to see where the lag is, and I'm pretty sure it's the socket itself where the lag is occurring. All of the data on the server side is written without blocking, but the client receives the end of the message after a lag. However I used getsockopt() to find the socket's receive and send buffers, and they are well over 512 bytes - 66000 and 130000 respectively. On the client side, I'm using express js to receive the data in a handler (app.on('data', function(){})). But I read that this express function does not buffer data?

Would anyone have a guess why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since TCP_NODELAY means send every piece of data as a packet as soon as possible without combining data together, it sounds like you are sending tons of packets.  Since you are writing one byte at a time it could send packets with just one byte of payload and a much bigger frame.  This would work fine most of the time but as soon as the first packet drops for whatever reason the receiver would need to go into error-correction mode on the TCP socket to ask for retransmission of the dropped packet.  That would incur at least one round-trip latency and perhaps several.  It sounds like you are getting lucky for the first several hundred packets (500 bytes worth) and then typically hitting your first packet drop and slowing way down due to error correction.  One simple solution might be to write in larger chunks, say 10 bytes at a time, instead of 1 byte so that the chance of hitting a dropped packet is much less.  Then you would expect to see this problem as often as you do only for messages around 5000 bytes or so.  In general setting TCP_NODELAY will cause things to go faster at first but wind up hitting the first dropped packet sooner simply because TCP_NODELAY will not decrease the number of packets you send per amount of data.  So it increases or leaves the number of packets the same which means your chance of hitting a dropped packet within a certain amount of data will go up.  There is a tradeoff here between interactive feel and first hiccup.  By avoiding TCP_NODELAY you can delay the typical amount of data that will be sent before the first error retransmission is hit on average.

Comment: Took your advice and wrote in bigger chunks when possible - it works great now, thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Get a network capture using tcpdump or wire-shark. Review the packet transmission time line, this will help distinguish network problems from software implementation issues. If you see retransmissions you may have a network issue, if you see slow acks you might find it better to NOT use 'No Delay' since Ack delay can stall a 'No Delay' connection.